# is it possible to have distinct + concat within group_concat?

Tags: php, mysql

I have this, as part of a bigger query:

```
CAST( GROUP_CONCAT( c.fname) AS char ) AS fname
, CAST( GROUP_CONCAT( c.lname ) AS char ) AS lname
```

I want something like:

```
CAST( GROUP_CONCAT( DISTINCT concat(c.fname,' ',c.lname) ) AS char ) AS user
```

Means, first I want to concat first name and last name, and then use the distinct to check whether the same firstname / lastname combination is not getting repeated. Possible using mysql or should I have to do that after using php?

Thanks guys.

Comment: I have same problem..but didn't get solution from below answer.. :(

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I made a test with some of my tables, and it worked for me:

```
SELECT GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT CONCAT(id,nombre)) FROM pre_departamento;
```

Comment: Thanks Pachin, but the idea was how to put all together, the distinct and concat within a group_concat, you see what I mean?

Comment: oh! a think I'm understanding now, I made a trivial test, and it worked for me. I edited my answer.

Comment: wow great, this is worderfully working. Many many thanks Pachin :)